# Selecting and Deselecting overlapping graphics in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, mouseevent, gis, drag

I am placing a line (lets call it line 1) on a canvas and attaching a mouse enter, mouse leave, mouse up and mouse down event to it. Another line (line 2) is then created with the same events attached. All events work perfectly when any of the lines are selected. 
For some reason when the first line that was created is dragged and released over the second line created the line does not get released on the canvas, however it remains glued to the mouse pointer until another click is made away from the second line. This problem occurs when the earliest lines created are dragged over the newer lines and not vice versa ( problem occurs when line 1 is dragged and released on line 2 but not vice versa, or line 1 over 2 and 3, and line 2 over line 3 etc.
I do not know what code might help regarding the solving of this issue, would anyone have any suggestions or maybe have encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the observed behavior is quite easily deduced:

All elements in a `Panel` do have an implicit z-order that will take effect when no [`ZIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex(v=vs.95).aspx) property is specified for en element. Earlier added elements have a lower z-order than later added elements (xaml markup is parse from top to bottom and elements that occur earlier are added earlier).

Now if you start moving elements around and two elements overlap the z-order is still effective. so your earlier added line will be treated as if it is physically beneath the other line, and all mouse events will go to the top-most line in the z-order. therefore the MouseUp event is not received by your moved element and it is still glued to the mouse pointer until you move your mouse away from the overlapping area and release the mouse again.

I can think of several ways to solve it:

Probably the easiest thing will be to just set an explicit `ZIndex` on the element as soon as you select it, when you move it around it will always be on top of all other elements, and when you release it anywhere you can clear the ZIndex again. Some example code to give you an idea:

```
private void OnElementSelected()
{
    // todo: maybe we need to store the previous zindex value and re-assign it later
    // to prevent it from getting lost
    Canvas.SetZIndex(this, Int32.MaxValue);
}

private void OnElementReleased()
{
    this.ClearValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty);
    // todo: maybe re-assign stored z-index value
}
```

An alternative solution would be to have a transparent MouseEventObserver placed over your whole `Canvas` that gets activated as soon as you select an element, then the order of your elements doesn't matter.

**Edit**

A nice fact (many devs probably are unaware of) about the `Canvas.ZIndex` attached property: it works for every panel type, not only for `Canvas`. So you can even specify the z-order of elements inside a `Grid` with `Canvas.ZIndex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply :)
In my case each element is already being given an explicit z-index when it is created, always one value greater than the previous element and yet this problem is still persistent. I attempted to change the z-index of the canvas on mouse up and mouse down as I have a property to show whether an element is being dragged or not, however this did not resolve the problem. Might there be some other issue? And thank you for your patience.

Comment: It does not matter whether you assign an explicit and successively incremented Z-Index property or whether the implicit z-order takes effect. Whenever you move an earlier added element around it will inevitably lie below those that have been added later. You must therefore ensure that the currently selected and moved element has the highest of all z-indices that exist at the moment. And I can't see why manipulating the z-index of the canvas should resolve the issue in any way.